# vector subscript out of range for loop in C++

Tags: c++

I keep on receiving this error `vector subscript out of range` when I run the below section of my code its triggered on this line `interval.push_back (peaks_position_vector[n+1]-peaks_position_vector[n]);`

I think the issue is with the victor size as im going over the vector size. I tried to initialize n with 100 to test it and decrements n. the error didn't occur. can some one help how can I fix it according to my requirements ? thanks in advance. ( feel free to ask about other sections of the code I only mentioned this part as this is where the error occurred only.)

```
double ECG::compute_heart_rate(vector<double>& peaks_position_vector)
{
    const int s = 60; // 'const' for good practice such that the variable s never changes in execution
    vector<double> interval;
    // compute pair-wise differences
    for (unsigned int n = 0; n < peaks_position_vector.size()-1; n++)
    {
        interval.push_back (peaks_position_vector[n+1]-peaks_position_vector[n]);

        // create heart rate vector
        vector<double> heart_rate;
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < interval.size()-1; j++)
        {
            double hh = s/interval[j];
            heart_rate.push_back(hh);


            // calculate mean heart rate
            double mean_heart_rate, return_value = 0;
            int x= 0;


            for (unsigned int i=0; i < heart_rate.size(); i++)
            {
                return_value += heart_rate[i];
                x++;

                mean_heart_rate = return_value / x;

            }

        }


    }


} // end of code block
```

Comment: Are you sure that `peaks_position_vector` is never size 0 or 1? How is it initialized?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I didn't initialize it `vector<double> peaks_position_vector;` and yes they are never 0 or 1

Comment: Instead of guessing, why not run your code in a debugger and  see where it crashes exactly along with which index it tried to access? Or step through and check your assumptions?

Comment: @Botje I already did that! thats why I mentioned exactly the line where it crashes.

Comment: `0 - 1` is a _very_ large number when treated as unsigned.

Comment: Well, if `peaks_position_vector` is empty (i.e. `size()` is equal to `0`), then `peaks_position_vector.size()-1` is a huge number. Looking for similar questions now.

Comment: @GG_Programmer_ZZ Then you also know the size of `peaks_position_vector` and n.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen your right I have fixed it. but the debugger doesn't enter the second loop. any idea?

Comment: @Botje I didn't give `peaks_position_vector` a size.

Comment: You didn't, but the compiler did. And the debugger can read the vector's size from memory, as well as tell you what the expression `peaks_position_vector.size()-1` resolved to.

Comment: @Botje thank you I didn't know this before. i will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that

```
n < peaks_position_vector.size()-1
```

should be

```
n + 1 < peaks_position_vector.size()
```

Suppose `peaks_position_vector.size()` equals zero, what do you think that `peaks_position_vector.size()-1` evaluates to given that `size()` returns an unsigned value, and zero is the smallest possible unsigned value?

Comment: Thank you what you mentioned makes sense and I fixed it in the program but now it doesn't enter the second loop for j. any Idea why ?

Comment: Your debugger should tell you that pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation you have mention have a bug with divided by zero problem. Where you are doing this you consider a vector input as {4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5}

```
interval.push_back (peaks_position_vector[n+1]-peaks_position_vector[n]);
....
....
double hh = s/interval[j];
heart_rate.push_back(hh)
...
...
return_value += heart_rate[i];
```

as you can see that would mess up `return_value` in your case( should have a value of inf ). And of course what @john have mentioned in the earlier answer also holds true.